# How to prevent webgl to clean canvas on every frame draw

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to display multiple frames from different streams in a single canvas, using viewports and calling draw function on every frame I have to render. What I'm trying to replicate is a camera videowall that uses only one canvas and one webgl context. The problem is that, every time I render a frame into a specific viewport, then the other frames I rendered before in a different viewport, it disappear.

I even tried to initiate the webgl context setting "preserveDrawingBuffer" attribute to true, but it does not solved.

Following the code I'm using:

```
this.drawNextOuptutPictureGL = function (par) {

        var gl = this.contextGL;

        var texturePosBuffer = this.texturePosBuffer;
        var uTexturePosBuffer = this.uTexturePosBuffer;
        var vTexturePosBuffer = this.vTexturePosBuffer;

        var yTextureRef = this.yTextureRef;
        var uTextureRef = this.uTextureRef;
        var vTextureRef = this.vTextureRef;

        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;

        var yData = par.yData;
        var uData = par.uData;
        var vData = par.vData;

        var yDataPerRow = par.yDataPerRow || width;
        var yRowCnt = par.yRowCnt || height;

        var uDataPerRow = par.uDataPerRow || (width / 2);
        var uRowCnt = par.uRowCnt || (height / 2);

        var vDataPerRow = par.vDataPerRow || uDataPerRow;
        var vRowCnt = par.vRowCnt || uRowCnt;

        var viewportRow = par.viewportRow;
        var viewportColumn = par.viewportColumn;

        // Calculate coordinates basing on a square matrix
        var square = Math.sqrt(this.viewports.length);
        var x = (this.canvasElement.width / square) * (viewportColumn - 1);
        var y = (this.canvasElement.height / square) * (square - viewportRow);

        gl.viewport(x, y, width, height);

        var tTop = 0;
        var tLeft = 0;
        var tBottom = height / yRowCnt;
        var tRight = width / yDataPerRow;
        var texturePosValues = new Float32Array([tRight, tTop, tLeft, tTop, tRight, tBottom, tLeft, tBottom]);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texturePosBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texturePosValues, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        if (this.customYUV444) {
          tBottom = height / uRowCnt;
          tRight = width / uDataPerRow;
        } else {
          tBottom = (height / 2) / uRowCnt;
          tRight = (width / 2) / uDataPerRow;
        };
        var uTexturePosValues = new Float32Array([tRight, tTop, tLeft, tTop, tRight, tBottom, tLeft, tBottom]);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uTexturePosBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uTexturePosValues, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);


        if (this.customYUV444) {
          tBottom = height / vRowCnt;
          tRight = width / vDataPerRow;
        } else {
          tBottom = (height / 2) / vRowCnt;
          tRight = (width / 2) / vDataPerRow;
        };
        var vTexturePosValues = new Float32Array([tRight, tTop, tLeft, tTop, tRight, tBottom, tLeft, tBottom]);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vTexturePosBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vTexturePosValues, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, yTextureRef);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, yDataPerRow, yRowCnt, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, yData);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, uTextureRef);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, uDataPerRow, uRowCnt, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, uData);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, vTextureRef);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, vDataPerRow, vRowCnt, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, vData);

        // draw image
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Is there a way to just update a specific viewport without having the entire context to be cleaned?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to render to textures and then render these textures to a canvas. This is just a hint. See this for more details: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html

Comment: Yes I already took a look at that article. So the way should be to draw on a texture using framebuffer, then render to default buffer (canvas) and then use previous texture as input for next frame that comes, right?
It is not so clear how retrieve the modified texture to re-use as input..

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the scissor test and set the scissor rectangle

```
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
gl.scissor(x, y, width, height);
```

Example:

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// compiles shaders, links program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCylinderBufferInfo(gl, 1, 1, 24, 1);

const scenes = [
  { 
     viewport: [0, 0, 150, 150],
     xRot: 0, 
     zRot: 0, 
     bg: [1, 0, 0, 1], 
     color: [0, 1, 1, 1],
  },
  { 
     viewport: [150, 0, 150, 50],
     xRot: Math.PI * .5, 
     zRot: 0, 
     bg: [0, 1, 0, 1], 
     color: [1, 0, 1, 1],
  },
  { 
     viewport: [150, 50, 150, 100],
     xRot: 0, 
     zRot: Math.PI * 0.25, 
     bg: [0, 0, 1, 1], 
     color: [1, 1, 0, 1],
  },
];

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
 
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

  scenes.forEach((scene, ndx) => {
    gl.viewport(...scene.viewport);
    gl.scissor(...scene.viewport);
    
    gl.clearColor(...scene.bg);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
    const aspect = scene.viewport[2] / scene.viewport[3];
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 10;
    const matrix = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
    m4.translate(matrix, [Math.sin(time + ndx), 0, -4], matrix);
    m4.rotateX(matrix, scene.xRot, matrix);
    m4.rotateZ(matrix, scene.zRot, matrix);
    m4.rotateZ(matrix, time, matrix);
    
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    // calls gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      color: scene.color,
      matrix: matrix,
    });
    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

and if you are not rendering every viewport every frame then you'll need to pass in `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when creating the webgl context.

Example that only updates one viewport per frame

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl', {
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
});

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCylinderBufferInfo(gl, 1, 1, 24, 1);

const scenes = [
  { 
     viewport: [0, 0, 150, 150],
     xRot: 0, 
     zRot: 0, 
     bg: [1, 0, 0, 1], 
     color: [0, 1, 1, 1],
  },
  { 
     viewport: [150, 0, 150, 50],
     xRot: Math.PI * .5, 
     zRot: 0, 
     bg: [0, 1, 0, 1], 
     color: [1, 0, 1, 1],
  },
  { 
     viewport: [150, 50, 150, 100],
     xRot: 0, 
     zRot: Math.PI * 0.25, 
     bg: [0, 0, 1, 1], 
     color: [1, 1, 0, 1],
  },
];

let count = 0;
function render(time) {
  ++count;
  time *= 0.001;
 
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

  const ndx = count % scenes.length;
  const scene = scenes[ndx];
  gl.viewport(...scene.viewport);
  gl.scissor(...scene.viewport);

  gl.clearColor(...scene.bg);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = scene.viewport[2] / scene.viewport[3];
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 10;
  const matrix = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  m4.translate(matrix, [Math.sin(time + ndx), 0, -4], matrix);
  m4.rotateX(matrix, scene.xRot, matrix);
  m4.rotateZ(matrix, scene.zRot, matrix);
  m4.rotateZ(matrix, time, matrix);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: scene.color,
    matrix: matrix,
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```